# playframework 2.x tags Compilation error

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I want to create and use a `tag`, to reuse my html-component in playframework 2.

My tag: `/views/mytags/words_tag.scala.html`

Code:

```
@(words: List[String] = List())

<ul id="words">
    @for(word <- words) {
        <li> <a href="/article/@word" onclick="#">@word</a></li>
    }
</ul>
```

Try to use in my `index.scala.html`:

```
@import views.mytags._
@words_tag(words)
```

As result I have a compilation error on the page:

**illegal start of simple expression**
**app/views/index.scala.html at line 9.**

> @import views.mytags._

Why?

**Updated:
LOG is:**

> sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[illegal
>   start of simple expression]   at
>   sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$2$$anonfun$apply$15$$anonfun$apply$16.apply(PlayReloader.scala:349)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$2$$anonfun$apply$15$$anonfun$apply$16.apply(PlayReloader.scala:349)
>   ~[na:na]  at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:133)
>   ~[scala-library.jar:na]   at
>   sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$2$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(PlayReloader.scala:349)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$2$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(PlayReloader.scala:346)
>   ~[na:na]  at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:133)
>   ~[scala-library.jar:na]

Answer (score 0):

your file named `words_tag.scala.html`, not `words_tags`. The difference in last `s`

Comment: ah..not it is my mistake in the question. in the code there is no mistake. I use "words_tag". Updated/fixed the question. And it point to "@import views.mytags._" that stand before that line

Answer (score 0):

Try importing views.**html**.mytags._

Answer (score 0):

It seems I know the reason. Will check it latter.

I need to use **import mytags._** without "views".

It is not obvious but that what the documentation says about this.